# How to install/run autohotkey without admin privileges?

Tags: macros, autohotkey

I followed this tutorial: http://www.thenickmay.com/articles/how-to-install-autohotkey-without-admin/

At Step #6, I opened AutoHotkeyU64.exe and it opened up the help file for AutoHotKey.

Then I went through the tutorial and tried out the script they give:

```
^j::
Send, My First Script
return
```

I saved this as tutorial.ahk, then opened a new notepad file and pressed ctrl+j. Nothing happened.

Anyone know what's going on? I've never used autohotkey before, btw.

Comment: Did you try saving it as **AutoHotkey.ahk** and also in the same folder as the EXE file?

Comment: Just tried it. Unfortunately doesn't work... but I'm not getting any error messages either.

Comment: Tried both putting the AutoHotkey.ahk in the same folder as the EXE file and in My Documents folder (where the folder containing the EXE file is)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since I was able to install it normally, I can't say for certain, but I believe there is a skipped step (or two) in the instructions.

After step 5, run (double-click) your .ahk script. If you get a message asking 
"How do you want to open this file", choose "More apps", then "Look for another app on this PC" (see image below), then navigate to and choose `AutoHotkey.exe` or `AutoHotkeyU64.exe`. Be sure to keep the checkbox checked to "Always use this app to open .ahk files" so that you only need to do this once on your machine.

[image: "How do you want to open this file" image]

Comment: brah you've saved my life. I didn't have admin right to install autohotkey but I couldn't live without swapping the capslock with ctrl. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I am late to the party and dunno if anyone's left drinking here, but I want to run ahk just to fix that darn copy/paste function on cmd/erp ... Hope this works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).